# Calculating torque for an evenly distributed force

Tags: torque

I'm imagining a hypothetical 2D post with a height of H.  It's going to be planted in the ground to a specified depth D.  It will be resisting a uniform force ( on the above ground portion) coming from one side (Wind).

The torque is relative to the distance from the pivot point, but the force is uniform, there is no one point at which it is applied. What's the best strategy to find the total torque exerted by the wind?   Do we take the sum of the force at various heights?  Do we calculate the total force and then pick a specific height?

I know a specific answer would depend on lot of details I have left out, but i'm looking for a general way to think about and tackle such problems where a force is applied uniformly and not from a specific point.

Comment: Both options give the same result if the force is distributed evenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the torque you replace the distributed force by a single force. If the force is uniform it is equivalent to a single force applied in the middle point between ground surface and the top.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform force? the farther "higher you measure up the post, the greater effect the force has on the post as it is that much farther away from it's anchor point.
Measure the force at three points for an average force. the lowest being point of anchor, mid point and maximal point "top".